# Fastest way to make multiple GET requests with custom headers?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to make a get request to a dataframe of URL's and pass customer headers/cookies (approx 4,500 URL's). Below is my current implementation which sometimes takes over an hour. What is a faster way to accomplish this?

```
# Function to make requests for each URL
def make_requests (data_frame, website_site_map):
    success = []
    failures = []
    # Perform GET requests for each URL
    for ind in panda_out.index:
        # Make HTTP GET request to URL with headers/cookies
        try:
            mw_url = panda_out['loc'][ind] + '/?moov_rt=MW'
            logging.info('URL to send request: ' + mw_url) # This will print out every URL to be requested
            response = requests.get(mw_url, headers=custom_headers)
            # Test to see if the response headers contains the appropriate headers
            if 'x-rsf-handler' in response.headers or 'x-moov-t' in response.headers:
                #logging.info('MW Experience Confirmed, x-rsf-handler header present: ' + response.headers['x-rsf-handler'])
                #logging.info(response.cookies)
                success.append(mw_url)
            else:
                logging.error('NOT THE MW Experience, x-rsf-handler or x-moov-t headers not present')
                logging.error('Response Headers: ' + str(response.headers))
                logging.error('Response Cookies: ' + str(response.cookies))
                failures.append(mw_url)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as con:
            logging.error('Connection Error: %s', con)
            failures.append(mw_url)
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as to:
            logging.error('Timeout Error: %s', to)
            failures.append(mw_url)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            logging.error('General Exception: %s', err)
            failures.append(mw_url)

    print('Total Number of URLs in Dataframe for Sitemap %s: ' % (website_site_map) , panda_out["loc"].count())
    print('Total Number of Successful HTTP Get Requests for Sitemap %s: ' % (website_site_map) , len(success))
    print('Total Failures for Sitemap %s: ' % (website_site_map) , len(failures))
    print('Failed URLs for Sitemap %s:' % (website_site_map) , failures)
    return [website_site_map, panda_out["loc"].count(), len(success), len(failures), failures]
```

Comment: the generak idea to imrpove is to make the code "non-blocking" in one way or another. You could go for asyncio for example.

Comment: Since each request takes a while you could tinker with some multithreading to perform multiple requests at once

Comment: Hey Travis, welcome to Stack Overflow! Checkout [Async IO in Python: A Complete Walkthrough](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) or [Fast & Asynchronous in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-and-async-in-python-accelerate-your-requests-using-asyncio-62dafca83c33) for some insight into "concurrency" in Python